# Apply backdrop-filter: blur() ignoring page content under it

Tags: css

My problem is the following:
I have a webpage with a gradient background applied to the body with: `background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #ff0000, #022EA8, #ffa500);` and I have a sticky header, which has the following code:

```css
header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px;
  z-index: 100;
  border-radius: 50px;
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
  height: calc(20% - 40px);
  margin: 20px;
  backdrop-filter: blur(200px);
}
```

I would like backdrop-filter blur only to apply the blur using the body background, in order not to see the page's content through the blur. But for now, it doesn't.

Since stackoverflow dosen't render bcg gradient, you can see an example here: https://codepen.io/Paillat/full/jOvXMJK

Comment: Since it's been 2 hours and no one has volunteered an answer, I suspect that your question may need some clarification.  Can you provide us with a runnable example that illustrates the issue you are having, preferably presented as a [StackSnippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)?

Comment: Yes, added an example on this codepen, since stack snippets don't render background gradients, added a codepen.

Comment: What are you looking for exactly?
When I decrease the background-filter blur to 10px, the text underneath the header is nicely blurred (in Chrome).
When I increase the background-filter blur to an insanely high value, the body background's gradient is also getting blurred (in Chrome).
What isn't working as expected?

Comment: @StijnHooft I would like the blur to ignore the text underneath, so that tehre isn't even any trace of white in the blur.